# Is it possible to do backpacking through Europe for 15 days with 1000USD?

Tags: europe, international-travel, planning, backpacking, hitchhiking

This is the situation, I hope you can give me a hand:

> On October 10th of this year I have an academic trip to Paris, it will
> take place from that date until October 22th. The trip is completely
> paid by my University, including tickets from my country (Colombia) to
> France, hotels, food and transport.
>
> Now, It was proposed to me to stay some additional days if I want to, but the condition is that I must pay those days by myself.

This is what I've considered so far:

> **Time:** I can not stay for more than 16 days starting from 22-oct since I'm in an active academic semester; more precisely, I can stay at most until November 7th (*keep in mind this is only a **time** limitation and it's not related to budget or other type of limitations*)
>
> **Budget:** This is the hard thing. This opportunity got me with not so much money and I think I can only get about **1000 USD** for the additional days (*my local currency is very cheap compared to Euros and, it doesn't matter how much money I save here, in Europe, it will be only seen as one third of it*).

The following is what I've planned based on other's opinions, travelers blogs and maps, among other resources.

> **The global plan:** My initial idea is to travel Belgium, Netherlands, Germany, Czech Republic, Austria, Italy, Switzerland and go back to Paris given that my return flight leaves from there (Yeah, I know it, it's a very long trip with a very adjusted budget and time, that's why I need some help).
>
> **The specifically plan:** I finish my academical things in Paris on October 22th, but I have paid accommodation until October 23th. My idea is to leave that day and head to Belgium, where I want to visit *Bruges*, then *Amsterdam* - Netherlands. In that moment, I'll head to *Prague*, crossing the German territory. After that, I'll go down through Austria to *Venice*, then *Milan* and then I'll return to Paris crossing Switzerland.
>
> **How am I planning to achieve it:** The first thing is that I'm planning to have and adventure, I'm not afraid (I know I must and in some sense, I like it) of having austere conditions or being limited. I plan to travel by **hitchhicking**, I've traveled my country by that mean and I've read it's even more feasible on Europe (I need some advices about this item!), however, I'm sure I'll need to make use of some public transport in order to get out from some cities or stuff like that.
>
> About the nights, I had in mind three things: The first one is to use **CouchSurfing**, I've never used it and I have an account on it with no references so that's probably an issue, however, I'll give a try and see how does it go (any advice with this? how should I ask? what should I add to the basic information?). The other option was **to camp**, I've never been out of my country and I don't know what temperature should I expect and probably this is not a feasible option, but it's present anyway. The last one is to use **hostels**, I've booked some prices and they seem feasible but half of my budget would be spent on accommodation if I sleep that way all days.
>
> I can buy my own **ingredients** and **cook**, provided I have a kitchen.
>
> **Additional info:** I must add that my plan is not to visit "famous cities" or "touristic places", I'm a lover of nature, landscapes, small villages and towns so that's something to keep in mind (however, Amsterdam, Bruges, Venice, Praga, all of them are touristic places! but they're not the priority, for example, I'm not planning to sleep on those sites or stay for much time). Also, I'm a man and I'm 21, if that's useful.

Well, those are all of my thoughts, this is a very important thing for me and I really hope you will help me, I'm on Math Stack Exchange and I know the friendliness and will of help of this community.

All the info I've gained comes from blogs and that kind of things, I've never asked someone personally or asked on forums, this is the first time.

Please give me your advices, recommendations and **opinions**, with no fear, if you tell me *You're dreaming, that's impossible* and give me good arguments, I'll take it at the best way. Also, I can change the plan, of course, I hear suggestions about other possible routes (maybe smaller) and other kind of things to do.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** My budget is precisely **3'000.000 COP**, USD is a little bit expensive these days so the convertion gives about 1.000 USD, but it can be a little bit more.

Comment: Sounds like fun.  Your agenda is too aggressive for 16 days, but that's strictly an opinion.  Also given your preference for landscapes and small villages and the month of October, consider a heavier weight on the Danube valley.   But all this is strictly an OPINION.  Grain of salt and etc...

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it (It looks amazing from what I can see in Google).

Comment: If you're on that much of a budget, I would recommend just completely avoiding Switzerland. Holy *crap* is Switzerland expensive (or at least Zurich was, that's the only city in Switzerland I've been, but last year, in Zurich, it was like 20 bucks for a cheap hamburger type expensive. Never doing that again.) Just the exchange rate alone was killer, but stuff was also expensive locally - put them together and it was madness.

Comment: Although the question sounds funny, i flagged as primarily opinion-based

Comment: @him That's a shame. Please redirect me, if possible, to a more adequate forum for my question. Thanks. (I can't imagine a lot of non-primarily opinion based question on this site, maybe my mistake was to add the words 'opinion', 'advice', etc).

Comment: As you are short on budget, and most of your listed countries are in the expensive range, I would look for a change in where you want to go. Fast travel (plane?) to Czech republic, add Slovakia, Poland, maybe also Hungary. Go slower, less expensive as well.

Comment: @SolidSnake: Stack Exchange is not a forum, it's a QA site. Another QA site that has a totally open policy on type of question is [Quora](http://www.quora.com). It's more like a forum than SE. SE is for questions that have one specific factually correct answer and don't hinge on opinion and discussion.

Comment: @SolidSnake don't go to Switzerland. As mentioned by another user in the comments, it's extremely expensive, 10 euros for a kebab, around 35 euros to stay in a dorm in a hostel, and crazy expensive trains (unless you have an annual half price card, which you only get if you live there). Forget about it.

Comment: @SolidSnake my tips: use couchsurfing, hostels, and airbnb, camping is not an option in October. Use blablacar for car sharing. 16 days is not much time at all, so reduce the number of countries you want to see to 4 or 5 maximum I would say.

Comment: I decided it's not too opinion based. It's a yes/no question and it is possible, but not at a level everybody would enjoy. (I have less than $1500 and I'm seriously considering traveling to Europe from China on that amount.) So I submitted an answer with similar info to what's already in the comments.

Comment: Buses are not that bad. When booked early, companies like megabus offer extremely cheap tickets (sometimes as low as 1$).

Comment: Looking at this again, I estimate 9 days total on the road hitching between the 8 destinations.  That leaves 7 days for touring the 8 destinations.  Doesn't work.  Not feasible.  Take some prozac and recast your itinerary.  If you think my hitching estimate is wrong, ask a new question about how many hours/days to hitch between those destinations.  Couch to couch would be the most accurate, but city centre to city centre can be a proxy.

Comment: There is a very similar question on Quora with several answers, including one by myself: [How can one plan for a backpacking trip to Europe with a budget under $1000?](http://www.quora.com/How-can-one-plan-for-a-backpacking-trip-to-Europe-with-a-budget-under-1000)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments. I'm considering (and probably will) changing my itinerary to this one: From Paris, go to Bruges and then Amsterdam. From there, head to Berlin and then Wroclaw, Poland. From there, go to Prague and then cross Germany to Strasbourg, from where I go to Paris (there's not a particular reason why I chose so many capitals). It's 40% shorter than the first itinerary, I'll do my best research and effort to make it possible.

Comment: @SolidSnake Paris to Bruges to Amsterdam is easy and cheap by bus/train (eurolines.com), Amsterdam to Berlin you probably want to fly (low cost flight, easyjet or else, look on skyscanner.com). Berlin to Wroclaw to Prague maybe bus, train or car sharing. Prague to Strasbourg: take a plane (low cost company if possible), look at flying to Mulhouse and take a train to Strasbourg from there. Book your fights in advance if you want cheap prices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Is it possible? Yes.**

I usually budget $1,000 per month wherever I travel. **But...**

But I use most of the tricks in the book, depending on the country, to keep prices down. Many people won't be comfortable with some or all of the tricks.

- Hitchhiking. No trains, no buses. When hitching fails, use ride sharing.
- Camping. Wild if possible. Finding cheap campgrounds varies a lot from place to place. In high season it's hard to get a space even if you can find campgrounds.
- Couch surfing and other hospitality networks.
- Stay at friends places whenever possible. Make friends during your travels who are from a country you intend to visit soon. But 15 days isn't much time to do  that.
- Cook your own food when you can. Or buy food from supermarkets, especially discount ones such as Lidl and Aldi. Street food and fast food such as kebabs are usually the cheapest hot foot in most parts of Europe. You can't afford restaurants very often on your budget - not even McDonalds really.

If the tricks I listed sound too harsh, consider a shorter time or allow for coming home early if the money runs out. The easiest way to stretch the money is to avoid the most expensive places like Zurich unless you have a relative or friend there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Hippietrail, and all the other kind people that wrote in the comments section. All this information is extremely useful to plan my trip. My conclusion is that **it is feasible but probably I must change my itinerary**. It's a shame this was flagged as Primarily Opinion-Based, but you guys are right, I know how SE works.

Comment: On my first Europe trip I intended not to visit Switzerland or England due to costs but along the way I made a travel friend from Switzerland and got an invitation from an old travel friend from another trip to stay at his place in London. So my advice is to expect to miss the most expensive places but be flexible because you never know.

Comment: @hippietrail what about busking? It does help when on a budget ;) and you meet great people!

Comment: @AdrienBe: Yep I think I mentioned it in my longer answer on Quora. My answer here is smaller since the question was getting closed. Also I haven't tried it myself yet (-: